# Detecting global destruction in Perl

Tags: perl, destroy

I'd like to detect if my object is being `DESTROY`'d as part of global destruction, and print out a warning (as that'd clearly be an error and lead to data loss). The obvious way to do that would seem to be:

```
sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    # ⋮
    if (i_am_in_global_destruction()) {
        warn "I survived until global destruction";
    }
}
```

but I have been unable to find a good way to detect global destruction (instead of normal refcount hit 0 destruction).

By "good way", I mean not this, which though it works on 5.10.1 and 5.8.8, probably breaks the second someone gives it an odd glance:

```
sub DESTROY {
    $in_gd = 0;
    {
        local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { $_[0] =~ /during global destruction\.$/ and $in_gd = 1 };
        warn "look, a warning";
    }
    if ($in_gd) {
        warn "I survived until global destruction";
    }
}'
```

Comment: Why not simply save your object contents when it is DESTROYed, and not worry about whether it is during global destruction or not?

Comment: @Ether: Because the order of global destruction is undefined, and I need other objects to save mine.

Comment: I see (from the `Devel::GlobalDestruction` source) that in v5.13.7 there is a [`${^GLOBAL_PHASE}`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.13.9/pod/perl5137delta.pod#New_global_variable_${^GLOBAL_PHASE}) variable that suits this purpose.

Comment: See also: http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.13.9/pod/perlvar.pod#GLOBAL_PHASE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a module [Devel::GlobalDestruction](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Devel%3a%3aGlobalDestruction) that uses a tiny bit of XS to let you get at the global destruction flag directly.

**Update:** since [perl 5.14.0](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5140delta) there is a global variable `${^GLOBAL_PHASE}` that will be set to `"DESTRUCT"` during global destruction. You should still generally use Devel::GlobalDestruction, since it works with perls back to 5.6. When installing on a perl with `${^GLOBAL_PHASE}` it will use the built-in feature and not even require a C compiler to build.

Comment: Thank you! And it's even packaged for Debian as `libdevel-globaldestruction-perl`, since Lenny no less.

Answer (score 8):

A solution that is good enough for me is to set a flag in an `END` block.

```
package Whatever;
our $_IN_GLOBAL_DESTRUCTION = 0;
END {
    $_IN_GLOBAL_DESTRUCTION = 1;
}
```

Comment: That won't necessarily work, as other packages' END blocks may get executed before that one is.

Comment: Also, global destruction technically occurs after all the END blocks are completed -- so the worst case here is that it could flag something incorrectly while it's being destroyed in another END block.